# Red Yucca (Hesperaloe parviflora) deficiency

Tags: urban-gardening, native-plants

Recently plant red yucca seems to have been sprayed or some reason becoming burnt, the soil was lightly composted to restore Ph unless this is a bug problem?

[![enter image description here][1]]

Comment: Can you post a more clearer picture of the damaged part?

Comment: Probably not until next week, they look like maybe a big is enjoying them too, but I thought it had to be burned because the pink blooms are dropping.